# Оптимизация вычисляемого свойства Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Есть вот такая модель:

```
public class Genre : DbObject
{
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();

    public virtual int BooksCount => Books.Count;
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, то при каждом обращении к `BooksCount` будет происходить запрос к базе чтобы подсчитать количество обьектов в коллекции `Books`. Может есть какой-то подход чтобы свойство `BooksCount` перезаписывалось только в момент изменения коллекции или есть какие-то другие способы усовершенствовать этот подход ?

Comment: а почему нельзя сделать простой get-private set и привязать в нему член _booksCount, который обновлять при изменении коллекции? Или Вас интересует именно в рамках вычисляемого свойства?

Comment: @Sleeeper, Да впринципе можно, но хотелось бы узнать какие еще есть варианты.

Comment: Не при каждом - а только при первом, если коллекция не была инициализирована ранее.